# In Julia, creating a Weights vector in statsbase

Tags: julia

I am playing a bit with Julia.

Consider this function:

```
function drawValues(fromDistribution, byCount)

#=
inputs:
fromDistribution : 
    A 2D array
    Each element is an array with two elements
    The first one is a value, and the second one is the probability of that value
    We will draw a value out of this distribution from a random number generator
    
byCount :
    An integer
    We draw that many values from the source distribution

=#



values = []
wts    = []

for i = 1:length(fromDistribution)
    
    push!(values, fromDistribution[i][1])
    push!(wts   , fromDistribution[i][2])
    
end


w = Weights(wts)

res = []

for i = 1:byCount
    
    r = sample(values, w)
    push!(res, r)
    
end


plot(values, wts)
print(res)


end
```

This throws the error :

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Weights(::Array{Any,1},
> ::Float64) Closest candidates are:   Weights(::var"#18#V",
> ::var"#16#S") where {var"#16#S"<:Real, var"#17#T"<:Real,
> var"#18#V"<:AbstractArray{var"#17#T",1}} at
> /home/hedgehog/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/weights.jl:13
> Weights(::Any) at
> /home/hedgehog/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/weights.jl:16
> Stacktrace:  [1] Weights(::Array{Any,1}) at
> /home/hedgehog/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/weights.jl:16  [2]
> drawValues(::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}, ::Int64) at
> /home/hedgehog/LASER.jl:51  [3] top-level scope at REPL[13]:1  [4]
> run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at
> /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/REPL/src/REPL.jl:288

It seems, that the second definition ( `Weights(::Array{Any,1})`) whould fit. But somehow Julia sees two input arguments?

Please help.

Version details :

> Julia Version 1.5.3
> Commit 788b2c77c1* (2020-11-09 13:37 UTC)
> Platform Info:
> OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
> WORD_SIZE: 64
> LIBM: libopenlibm
> LLVM:
> libLLVM-10.0.1 (ORCJIT, znver2)

Comment: Write `values = first.(fromDistribution)` and `wts = last.(fromDistribution)` instead of the loop.

Comment: This is the same post as [on the Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/using-weights-from-statsbase-in-julia-and-using-an-array/50820). Please don't cross-post, or at least give links to avoid wasting people's time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Vector`s have elements of type any.

It should be:

```
wts = Float64[]
```

When you write `wts=[]` it is an equivalent of `wts=Any[]`.

Have a look at the `weight` methods:

```
julia> methods(weights)
# 3 methods for generic function "weights":
[1] weights(vs::AbstractArray{T,1} where T<:Real) in StatsBase at c:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.3\packages\StatsBase\EA8Mh\src\weights.jl:76
[2] weights(vs::AbstractArray{T,N} where N where T<:Real) in StatsBase at c:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.3\packages\StatsBase\EA8Mh\src\weights.jl:77
[3] weights(model::StatisticalModel) in StatsBase at c:\JuliaPkg\Julia1.5.3\packages\StatsBase\EA8Mh\src\statmodels.jl:143
```

A container having elements of subtype of `Real` is required.

Similarly for the other containers providing the types is recommended as well:

```
value = Float64[]
res = Float64[]  # or maybe Int[] depending on what your code does
```